# Swift - Check if array contains element with property

Tags: arrays, swift

I have an array of custom objects.

I want to check if array contains an object, which property is equal to string.

Something like

```
 if array.contains(object where object.name == name) {
     // do something
 } else {
     // don't do something
 }
```

How to do in Swift?

Comment: Fun fact: I copy and pasted your question title into google, and ^ that was the first result – please always make sure to do some research before asking.

Answer (score 147, accepted):

Yes,

```
if things.contains(where: { $0.someProperty == "nameToMatch" }) {
     // found
} else {
     // not
}
```

Comment: This code does not compile.

Comment: @appzYourLife it does compile in Swift 3. Example: `if ["a", "b"].contains(where: { $0.capitalized == "A" }) { }`

Comment: One thing to note if you get errors is that the objects that you are comparing must be comparable if your array contains custom objects. Either add the equatable functions for that object type or check specific properties of the type. In the example in this answer it is assumed that the someProperty property is a string

Comment: how could you tweak this to find the index of said value `$0`?