# Swift: Checking if a member exist in a struct

Tags: swift

For the following code, how can I check if a member "b" or "f" exist for myArray?

```
struct example {

    var a: String!
    var b: Bool!
    var c: Bool!
    var d: String!

}

var myArray = [example]!
```

For example, if I check if member "f" exists, I would like something to return "false" or "nil"; and if I check if "b" exists, I would like to receive "true".

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift - Check if array contains element with property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37988431/swift-check-if-array-contains-element-with-property)

Comment: It is Swift convention to name your structures starting with an uppercase letter. Btw it is really poor Swift design to make all your struct properties implicitly unwrapped optionals. You should also declare all your properties as constants. If you need to change one of the properties just instantiate a new structure object

Comment: Also whats the meaning of checking if your struct has a `f` property? I think what you are looking for is a dictionary and check if a key exist.

Comment: @LeoDabus Objective-C had mechanisms in `objc/runtime.h` that could do exactly this. It had its occasional uses. Swift doesn't support this, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike Objective-C, Swift does not have the dynamic mechanisms to do things like this. So the answer is that no, you cannot check for members by name in this way, unless you are working with members of an `NSObject` subclass which are marked with the `@objc` attribute.

Comment: This is no longer true since the introduction of [Mirror](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/mirror).

Answer (score 1):

Using `Mirror`.

```
let example = Example()
let containsB = Mirror(reflecting: example).children.contains { $0.0 == "b" } // true
let containsF = Mirror(reflecting: example).children.contains { $0.0 == "f" } // false
```

```
let examples = [Example(), Example(), Example()]
let containsA = examples.filter {
    Mirror(reflecting: $0).children.contains { $0.0 == "a" }
}.isEmpty == false // true
```

Answer (score -1):

As others have commented, there are other problems with your example, but assuming you know and are just throwing out a quick and dirty sample to illustrate your question, you could do something a bit like this:

```
if let bExists = myArray.b {
  return true
} else if let fExists = myArray.f {
  return false // or return nil, or whatever you want to do if `f exists.
}
```