# How to check if already custom object exist in array?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, xcode, swift4

I have a array of object of custom class. My class is Person. So i want to check if arrPerson contains an object then it should not be added again in array.

Here is my code

```
for value in data {

    if self.arrPerson.contains(where: {($0.id != value.id)}){
        self.arrPerson.append(value)
    }
}
```

Please tell me how can i check if object of custom class already added then it should not be added again

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37988431/swift-check-if-array-contains-element-with-property

Comment: That does not answer my question

Comment: if you don't want to compare any property you can just compare the object {($0 == value)}

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
if !self.arrPerson.contains(where: {($0.id == value.id)}){
    self.arrPerson.append(value)
}
```

Comment: only write if !self.arrPerson.contains(where: {($0.id == value.id)}){
    self.arrPerson.append(value)
}

Answer (score 1):

You can use "set" instead of array it will avoid the duplicate values.